# Configuring Play Application for MYSQL Database in Amazon EC2

Tags: mysql, playframework, amazon-ec2, playframework-1.x

I am trying to use a mysql database in my play 1.2.4 application hosted in Amazon EC2 .
For that, I configured application.conf file with the following snippet in my local environment.

```
db=mysql:root:password@databasename
```

and this works fine.

Same mysql server have been configured in my EC2 instance with same Database created .

What should be the configuration to use that DB in EC2 . After several trial and error methods , I am not able to make my Play application talk with the database .

Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 2):

I would diagnose this problem with the following tests:

- Can you reach your mysql server from the same machine you are running your application from?
- When trying this, make sure that you use the same user and password as in your application.
- Have a look at the mysql users table and check if the user is allowed to connect.
- Is the mysql daemon bound to `localhost` or do you have to use the IP or external DNS name of the machine?
- Try checking your firewall rules that the port for mysql is open from your application machine
- Also check the EC2 Security group that the mysql port is open from your application machine.

Comment: Thanks Jones for the reply , Both my application and mysql server are running in the same EC2 instance . The user is root and it has the privileged to connect .  mysql port is open in ec2 security group.

Comment: I have a doubt in "Is the mysql daemon bound to localhost or do you have to use the IP or external DNS name of the machine?"